# How to allow cisco to log on to a specific ip port using nat

Tags: cisco, nat

Good afternoon, I use Cisco 7201
I create a network on the gi0/0 interface connecting to a dhcp provider and get a static ip address, also on the gi0/1 interface I create a network where my 5 servers are, then I forward ports from servers from the network to the gi0/0 interface and port 22 becomes accessible from the Internet, but here's the task of how to make access only by ip to the port, I don't want someone else to connect to my port, I have a static ip in another place and I want to enter port 22 only with this ip. prohibit other ip from logging in, tried many options, after the command in the interface, the Internet ip access-group 101 in disappears.

```
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.1.22 22 interface GigabitEthernet0/0 22 

access-list 101 permit tcp host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx any eq 22


ip nat inside source list 101 int gi0/0
```

I do such a sequence, the restriction does not work, everyone can enter port 22

```
ip nat inside source list 1 interface GigabitEthernet0/0 overload
ip nat inside source list 101 pool 12.161.45.13
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.1.22 22 interface GigabitEthernet0/0 22
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.1.25 150 interface GigabitEthernet0/0 150
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.1.22 80 interface GigabitEthernet0/0 80
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.1.21 21 interface GigabitEthernet0/0 21
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.1.21 77 interface GigabitEthernet0/0 77
!
logging alarm informational
access-list 1 permit 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 101 permit tcp host 48.125.14.23 any eq 22
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include your configuration. Extended access lists include both the source and destination addresses.

Comment: You are not applying the access list.

Comment: If I apply the ip access-group 101 in list, then my Internet connection disappears and there is no Internet on all servers

Comment: How are you applying the ACL? `ip nat inside source list <acl>`?

Comment: ip nat inside source list 101 int gi0/0

Comment: All your `ip nat inside source static tcp` commands are allowing any outside address; they are not using an extended ACL to only allow a specific outside address.